# Ajax/PHP upload with parameters (again...)

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I've read the many questions and answers on this, but I can't seem to get any of them working. I've reduced this to as small as I can to save brain space.

index.html:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var ajax = new XMLHttpRequest();
    someData = '9876324iuygweighfds';
    ajax.open("POST", 'http://www.server.com/ajaxTest.php?a=123', false);
    ajax.setRequestHeader("Content-type",'application/upload');
    ajax.send(someData); 
    document.write(ajax.responseText);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

ajaxTest.php:

```
<?php
$a = $_POST['a'];
echo "This is the server. <br>".$a."<br>";
?>
```

All I get back is:

> This is the server.

The actual goal is to send image data gleaned from a canvas and some parameters in one go. Driving me crazy. I'm probably missing something simple, so I thank you and apologise - it's been a very long day :-)

Comment: Try `$a = $_GET['a'];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `someData = 'a=123';` if you'd like to access it as a POST variable.

Alternatively you could change your PHP to `$a = $_GET['a'];`

Comment: I never knew POST and GET were interchangeable on the receiving script!Just had a quick scan of some tutorials and they never mention it. Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

You just need to change this part of your own code.

```
<?php
    $a = $_GET['a']; // HEREEEEEE \o
    echo "This is the server. <br>".$a."<br>";
?>
```